# Scroll to top button doesn't work on Android devices

Tags: javascript, css

I added Go to top button to a WordPress site. Works on desktop and iOS but I can't get it working on Android. Here is the site in question https://myfermentedfoods.com/

Here is what I did:

Added to style.css

```
#myBtn {
display: none;
position: fixed; 
bottom: 20px; 
right: 30px; 
z-index: 99; 
border: none; 
outline: none; 
background-color: #ffcc00; 
color: black; 
cursor: pointer; 
padding: 15px; 
border-radius: 10px; 
font-size: 18px; 
}

#myBtn:hover {
background-color: #fff4c8; 
}
```

Added to js

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >             
   50) {
document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
} else {
document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
}
}

function topFunction() {
document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me (Android 8.1.0 / Firefox 63.0.2). On what conditions did you test?

Comment: Android 8.1.0, Chrome 71.0.3